# Design bug when editing an old revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[Example](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/666/edit/185eca5e-17d2-4a2e-bc37-9dcfb75c993d):

[image: screenshot]

Reproduced in Chrome 8, Opera 11, and IE8.

This is how it appears in Safari 5.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.6.

[image: screenshot]

**Edit:** Bug is still present. Chrome 14 on Windows 7 looks just like above.

Comment: I see this too, on Chrome (9.0.597.102) on Mac OS X 10.6. In fact I see it even when editing the latest revision, if I click "edit" on the latest revision on a list of revisions page.

Comment: I see this too, on Chrome (12.0.742.9 dev) on Windows 7.

Comment: I see the same on Safari 5.1 running on Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, look at that... better late than never, eh? :)

This will be fixed in the next deployment. Keep an eye out for rev 2014.4.23.1564.

Comment: Looks good to me.